# Unable to get the scope data to the html page using factory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to send the same json data from home.js to content.js.But I'm unable to populate the  content.js scope data into the html page

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My home.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService',
                            function ($scope,myService) {

  $scope.list1= [];
         $scope.list2= [];

 var sampleItem = this.item;
            myService.setJson(sampleItem);

 $.each($scope.samples, function (i, x) {
                  if (x.name === sampleItem .secName && x.id === sampleItem .id) {

                     if (sampleItem .secName === $scope.secsList[0]) {

                        $scope.list1.push(x);


                     } 
                     else {

                        $scope.list2.push(x);
                     }
                     $scope.myData = x.dataList;


                  }
               });
               });
```

My content.js :

```
 angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('secondCtrl', function ($scope,myService) {

      $scope.myreturnedData = myService.getJson();

        console.log($scope.myreturnedData);

    })

  .factory('myService', function(){
    var sampleItem = null;
     return {
     getJson:function(){
       return sampleItem;
     },
     setJson:function(value){
      sampleItem = value;
     }
     }

});
```

My content.html :

```
  <div ng-controller="secondCtrl" > {{myreturnedData.sampleName}}</div>
```

My home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl" ng-repeat="item in list1" >
                        <div > {{item.sampleName}} </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please, provide full `html` code. I think, you have mistake in `controller` **firstCtrl** in `html`.

Comment: I had edited the code.In the home.html, I'm able to populate data but unable to display data in content.html.can u please help me out ...

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: ya,I've checked ur answer.Thanks a lot for ur info.I did the same thing in my code.But unable to populate the data in html page

Comment: Please, provide your code in **jsfiddle**. Then we can solve your problem.

Comment: If my solution correct, please set it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work  solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gq79f31s/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp',[])
  .controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

      $scope.sampleItem = {
        sampleName: "sampleName"
      };
      myService.setJson($scope.sampleItem);
    }
  )
  .controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.myreturnedData = myService.getJson();

    console.log($scope.myreturnedData);

  })
.factory('myService', function() {
  var sampleItem = null;
  return {
    getJson: function() {
      return sampleItem;
    },
    setJson: function(value) {
      sampleItem = value;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
  <h2>
  firstCtrl
  </h2>
    <input ng-model="sampleItem.sampleName">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="secondCtrl"> <h2>
  secondCtrl
  </h2>{{myreturnedData.sampleName}}</div>
</div>
```